# Find json count item

Tags: python, json

Here's the json I have

```
[
    {
        "count": 1,
        "item": "this"
    },...
]
```

I would like to print the count for `this`

```
for item in parsed:
    if 'item' in item is 'this':
        print item['count']
```

This doesn't seem to work what's wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `if 'item' in item is 'this':` to do?

Comment: Also, "This doesn't seem to work" is not descriptive of your error.  Can you be more specific?  I'm guessing you actually know that it doesn't work... how do you know?

Comment: I doesn't give the count item. It prints nothing.

Comment: What does it give?  That would be mighty helpful in debugging your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The line `if 'item' in item is 'this':` is what is getting you.  You need to  change this to `if item['item'] == 'this':`:

```
for item in parsed:
    if item['item'] == 'this':
        print item['count']
```

The line  `if 'item' in item is 'this':` is equivalent to `if ('item' in item) is 'this':` which would be checking if the object ID of a boolean equals the string `'this'`... that will never be true.

The `is` operator checks if the object ID of two objects are the same; that is *not* the same as `==` which checks if the values of two objects are the same.  In general, you will never use `is`, except if you want to see if a variable explicitly is `None`, (as in `if var is None`).